# Firebreath OnWindowAttached Event not being fired on chrome and opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, opera, firebreath

My chrome and opera are of the version 33 and 17 respectively. I read the firebreath plugin lifecycle thoroughly before asking this question.

**In my plugin.cpp onWinodowAttached Event, I am just invoking a method to get the plugin Handle after the attached event occurs.
Is the following JS code, an ideal way to capture onWindowAttached event in JS?**

This is my JS code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function plugin0()
{
    return document.getElementById('plugin0');
}
         plugin = plugin0;
 function addEvent(obj, name, func)
{
    if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on"+name, func);
    } else {
        obj.addEventListener(name, func, false); 
    }
}
 function pluginLoaded() {
           alert("Plugin loaded!");
           //alert(plugin().GetPluginHandle);
           }
function RegisterWindowAttached()
{
var domplugin=document.getElementById('plugin0');
    addEvent(domplugin, 'OnWindowAttached', function (pluginObj) {
        PluginOnWindowAttached(pluginObj);
    });
}
function PluginOnWindowAttached(pluginObj)
{
    alert("attached");
    alert(plugin().GetPluginHandle+"after attachement");
}
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="RegisterWindowAttached()">
 <object id="plugin0" type="application/x-mydemoplugin" width="400px" height="400px">
        <param name="onload" value="pluginLoaded" />
    </object><br />

    </body>
    </html>
```

P.S: 1.GetPluginHandle returns the AttachedWindow interms of long value and is a property.
     2.'OnWindowAttached' registered by FB_JSAPI_EVENT and working fine in IE and firefox.but different order of execution of alert statement coming. Why so?